# Why is my console.log('toto') not working in my GoogleStrategy with Passport and Express.js for Google OAuth2.0?

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

Callback problem with google Oauth2.0 with passeport and express.js

Here is my GoogleStrategy and my console.log("toto") is not working is assume my never been that far and I don't know why. That's weird because i can go to the google login page and then the redirection to the next page (/home) is working

```
import passport from "passport";
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
import { createUser } from '@methods/users/classic/create';

console.log('Start setupPassport');
export function setupPassport() {
    passport.use(
        new GoogleStrategy(
            {
                clientID: "ID",
                clientSecret: "SECRET",
                callbackURL: "http://localhost:8080/v1/auth/google/callback",
            },
            (accessToken: any, refreshToken: any, profile: any, done: any) => {
                console.log("toto")
                // done(null, user);
            }
        )
    );
    console.log('End setupPassport');
    
    passport.serializeUser((user: any, done) => {
        console.log("Inside serializeUser");
        done(null, user);
    });
    
    passport.deserializeUser((user: any, done) => {
        console.log("Inside deserializeUser");
        done(null, user);
    });
}

export const googleAuth = (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    console.log("Inside googleAuth handler");
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })(req, res, next);
};

export const logout = (req: Request, res: Response): void => {
    console.log("Inside logout handler");
    // req.logout();
};
```

Here is my controller and req.user is always undefined (8081 is my website and 8080 my server)

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { config } from '@config/envConfig';
import { getUserByMail } from '@methods/users/classic/get';
import { createUser } from '@methods/users/classic/create';

import { googleAuth, logout } from "@methods/oauth/oauth";

  const googleAuthHandler = googleAuth;

async function googleAuthCallback (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    console.log("Inside googleAuthCallback");
    const user = req.user;
    console.log(user)
    res.redirect("http://localhost:8081");
};

async function logoutHandler(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    // logout(req, res);
    res.redirect("/");
};

export { googleAuthHandler, googleAuthCallback, logoutHandler };
```

here are my routes

```
import { Express } from "express";
import * as loginController from "../controllers/login"
import * as googleUser from '../controllers/oauth'

export function loginRoutes(app: Express) {
    app.post('/v1/login', loginController.login)
    app.post('/v1/proLogin', loginController.proLogin)
    
    app.get('/v1/auth/google', googleUser.googleAuthHandler);
    app.get('/v1/auth/google/callback', googleUser.googleAuthCallback);
    app.get('/v1/logout', googleUser.logoutHandler);
}
```

Please i need help i hope my description is clear thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please do not include any secrets in your code you put online